# Python Global Variable Through Import?

Tags: python, import, global-variables

Is this form of global variable declaration good practice in Python?  My dictionary has no data in B.py in some cases.  Just seems inconsistent.

classes.py

```
class Aclass:
    dict = {}

myClass = Aclass()
```

A.py:

```
from classes import myClass

myClass.dict["variable"]
```

B.py:

```
from classes import myClass

print str(myClass.dict)
```

A.py is processed before B.py.  This prints an empty dict `{}` for me.

This is a simplified question from previous post: [Shared/Global Dictionary in Django Between URLs and Context Processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010797/shared-global-dictionary-in-django-between-urls-and-context-processor). Your insight is appreciated.

Comment: A.py does not do anything with the variables. It merely tries to access an entry in a dictionary. Did you mean to say `myClass.dict["variable"] = "value"` (or something to that effect)?

Comment: Wanted you all to know that the issue was slightly more insidious, and thank you for your help. It was importing the same files through two paths: one imported project.classes.myClass while the other imported just classes.myClass, creating two separate instances.  The post that this was reduced from is this one: [Shared/Global Dictionary in Django Between URLs and Context Processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010797/shared-global-dictionary-in-django-between-urls-and-context-processor)

Answer (score 2):

if in A.py you change it to

```
myClass.dict["variable"]="hello"
```

(as pointed out in comments)

then the question becomes interesting.

it's ok but it's better to have another interface (functions, methods) to that data. It's a way to store a state of the module. The object you called myClass (!) is the same both from a and b.

multiple imports are safe and do nothing except to return the same loaded module.

Comment: ... because modules that were imported before *(being in the same process, o.c.)* are saved in the `sys.modules` dictionary. :)